# Why there is no "romulan" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Romulans plays essentialy the same role (by sole number of apperances) in Star Trek franchise, like Klingon do. Yet, there is a [klingon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) tag, but no [romulan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romulan) one. Why? Should we have such?

Comment: Sure, why not create it?

Comment: Klingons do play a considerably greater role in Star Trek than do the Romulans.

Comment: Don't make all the changes at once, though. All those old questions will be pointlessly pushed to the front page.

Comment: @Null Are seven questions "all changes at once"? Cause that is all I wanted to mark with this new tag.

Comment: @Richard But, I think that here only number of questions justify, if particular tag is required. I have my own seven questions focused on Romulans. There are probably many, many more. So, I think, that such tag is required and just created it. I didn't know, that I don't need "super high rep" to create new tags.

Comment: @Null Personally I'd say seven was a few too many to do at once. I usually do no more than three or four at a time.

Comment: @alexwlchan Then I made a mistake, sorry. But, I think the bad thing has been done and I can't do nothing to reverse this, right (i.e. I can't reverse fact, that these old questions are pushed to front page; I can't of course reverse adding new tag, but this seems pointless right now)?

Comment: @trejder No, there's no way to unbump in from the front page; just bear it in mind the next time you want to edit a bunch of posts at once.

Comment: @alexwlchan Sure thing, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because nobody who's tag-obsessed posted Romulan centric questions and had an occasion to create one. Go ahead and add one to your questions.

Comment: God... this is that simple? :>

Comment: @trejder - yup. Either that, or it's a conspiracy by moderators and Graecus lovers and Vulcan toadies to suppress pro-Romulan sentiment.

Comment: @trejder Only simple [when at or above 300 rep](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) ;)

Comment: Now someone’s suggested an edit to the Romulan tag that says they’re a “human-like” species. I was so offended.